# How to handle loading of a view in Tridion's CME

Tags: tridion

I have an extension to the Tridion 2011 Content Manager Explorer where I want to execute a specific piece of JavaScript only for a specific view.

I do this with the following JavaScript fragment:

```js
var onDisplayStarted = function () {
    $evt.removeEventHandler($display, "start", onDisplayStarted);

    if ($display.getView().getId() == "PublishPopup") {
      ...
    }
};
$evt.addEventHandler($display, "start", onDisplayStarted);
```

This code has worked well in the past and it definitely triggers when the `PublishPopup` opens and ensures my code only executes in that specific view.

But unfortunately I sometimes get the following error message in the JavaScript console while loading the `DashboardView`:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getId'

The error doesn't cause any problems, most likely since errors in event handlers are handled correctly by Tridion's UI framework. But I'd still prefer to not have the error showing in the JavaScript console.

I understand how to detect if the `getId` method exists:

```js
if ($display.getView().getId && $display.getView().getId() == "PublishPopup") {
```

But that would just mean that the code doesn't execute ever. And although it seems to work fine in the `PublishPopup` right now, I'd rather know the proper way to handle this type of "my code should execute once the view has initialized" sequence.

Does anyone know a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there are two different views, which are loaded at the same time - Dashboard View and Tridion Dashboard View. Tridion Dashboard View is what you see when you click on SDL Tridion tab in Ribbon Toolbar. Indeed, this view doesn't have getId method (which is strange, btw). That's why you have this issue.

Nevertheless, the whole idea behind the file groups in configuraton file is to minimize amount of the javascript, loaded for each view and to minimize un-needed javascript processing. So I would recommend to split your javascript file into pieces and load them only oт necessity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Boris. The existence of two views indeed completely explains the behavior I am seeing. And it also means that I can safely ignore the Tridion Dashboard View. But you (and John) are right, splitting the script over two files would be even better.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have code in your configuration to only include your extension on the popup window? For example:

```
<cfg:extension target="Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Views.Popups.Publish">
```

I typically use that configuration to only run script on a specific view within the cme.

My js file then looks like this:

```
$evt.addEventHandler($display, "start", onDisplayStarted);

function onDisplayStarted() {

        $log.message("stuff here");
}
```

Comment: Hey John, thanks for your answer. Your approach is indeed exactly how I would normally do that. But in this case I have a single JavaScript file where only some parts need to be targeted to the `PublishPopup`. I could split the JavaScript into two files and use the configuration to target each, but I was hoping there would also be a way to do it in code. The `$display "start"` event works great, I just don't get why the getId method isn't available yet (and whether that is guaranteed to only happen on the `DashboardView`).